# Why is this SQL Server table using so much space

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We have a table in an Azure SQL Server DB that is using about **15x the expected used space** for the number of rows x average row size. This is occuring with a customer that uses Azure SQL (not managed instance), compared to other customers using AWS RDS or an on-prem SQL Server DB where the used space is good. The cause could be usage pattern related and not Azure related but I have compared customers that are quite similar.

This table holds report data and each day there are about 1-5 report runs inserting ~2M-20M rows each, and old reports are automatically deleted after 3-14 days (ie. also deleting 1-5 report runs daily but at a later date).

We extended the DB and ran a new report and it filled the DB again, using too much space for the row count and row size in the new report. To delete a report run we had to extended the DB again (because it was at the limit and DELETE FROM failed), this time by 50GB, deleted one report (DELETE FROM ReportRuns WHERE ID = x) which deleted ~20M rows and took many hours and oddly the **used space grew by 48GB**!

The issue was only identified after this customer a) upgraded our application (which by design now writes 6x the number of rows), and b) moved to a new Azure SQL DB. They could have very well been experiencing the problem with their previous DB but didn't notice because the row counts were much lower.

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE ReportDetails(
  [RunID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [FromDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [Period] [int] NULL,
  [Quantity] [float] NOT NULL,
  [Peak] [char](1) NULL,
  [GroupByValues] [varchar](500) NULL,
  [Statistic] [char](5) NULL,
  [Interval] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE ReportDetails  
WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ReportDetails_RunID] 
FOREIGN KEY([RunID]) REFERENCES [ReportRuns] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_REPORTDETAILS] ON ReportDetails
(
  [RunID] ASC,
  [FromDate] ASC,
  [Period] ASC,
  [Statistic] ASC
) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
  ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) 
  ON [PRIMARY]
```

Results using [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64037173/4119742) before we deleted the rows:

```
table_name       ReportDetails     ReportDetails
index_name                NULL  IX_REPORTDETAILS
object_type              TABLE             INDEX
index_type                HEAP      NONCLUSTERED
partition_count              1                 1
row_count            136901432         137498512
data_compression          NONE              NONE
total_space_MB       175139.38          11588.80
used_space_MB        175109.33           9704.92
unused_space_MB          30.05           1883.88
```

That's **1341 bytes per row on average**. The values in the GroupByValues varchar(500) column range from only 20 to max 62 characters, so I would have expected it to be around **80 bytes** per row.

And then after we deleted 20M rows:

```
index_name                NULL  IX_REPORTDETAILS
object_type              TABLE             INDEX
row_count            116347856         119155072
total_space_MB       222879.35          10059.18
used_space_MB        222842.63           8426.55
unused_space_MB          36.73           1632.63
```

The index appears to be behaving but **why does the table have 20M fewer rows but 47GB increase in space used?**

I have checked that there are no active transactions (that might be causing a build up of log entries, table lock, etc).

After a lot of trial and error and investigation I found that the **pages are barely used**. This is a 'DETAILED' sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats report for the HEAP/table:

```
fragmentation_percent  page_space_used_percent  page_count  alloc_unit_type_desc
          1.734230907               7.54381023    22413932           IN_ROW_DATA
```

It appears as though report runs are not using the free space in the pages. I would have expected the new report run would have used free space and not increased space used. And somehow deleting the report made things worse.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you explored creating a clustered index on this table to support the most common query patterns--such as creating the existing index as clustered, rather than non clustered?

Comment: Just to check the obvious; it's not the transaction log that grows and fills the disk, but the data file? Are there any indexes with funny fill factors?

Comment: [DELETE Operation in SQL Server HEAPs](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/delete-operation-sql-server-heaps/)

Comment: @AMtwo we actually wanted to add a clustered index in the app update (not to address this problem) but it required too much space during the DB upgrade as some smaller customers use SQL Server Express and the temp space needed pushed over the 10GB limit. We could explore ways to do that that are not automated I guess - dump table, create with clustered index, load from dump perhaps

Comment: @vonPryz I don't think tat is the case here. I would expect the page_space_used_percent to be for data pages only, and the only index on the table is listed in the original question and has no special fill factor and the index itself is actually behaving normally

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Thank you very much. I had assumed, likely incorrectly, that the 7.5% page space used meant that a small amount of most pages was being used but now it seems that it could be that a small number of pages are largely/fully used but the majority of pages are empty but were not deallocated. I don't understand though why all of the other databases we have checked (with larger and smaller reports/row counts) behave differently, and deallocate the unused pages from these same large DELETEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to digest / address here based on your description and responses so far, but I'll try to address the main things:

1. You should almost always have a clustered index on your tables. The clustered index itself doesn't add any *meaningful* overhead in space usage, because it **is** the data of your table itself, sorted on the fields you define it on, rather than a copy of the data like a nonclustered index is. (Note the fields you choose as the clustered index key do get stored in each additional nonclustered index you create too, for facilitating key lookups, so there is a little extra overhead there if you use nonclustered indexes as well).

2. Ironically, the fact that you're not using a clustered index could very well be your problem because of the way a table without a clustered index, aka a Heap, stores data. The [link in Dennis's comment on Heaps](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/delete-operation-sql-server-heaps/) does a great job explaining how this can be an issue relevant to your particular case.
3. Outside of the above, I'm with vonPryz on verifying your [fill factor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index?view=sql-server-ver15) setting and that the [Transaction Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)
   growth settings and / or it's backups aren't the stem of your issues if it isn't anything related to the Heap table you have (as discussed in the linked article in point #2). These are some things that can easily be configured differently between one database and another that would result in some of the behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: Thanks. We have added a clustered index for this customer and will be checking the space used over the coming days. I will return to accept the answer if the issue is solved.

Comment: We monitored the space used by the table over a few weeks after adding the clustered index and it stabilised to a low and expected level. The many repeated inserts and deletes are no longer preventing the pages from being reused. Thank you!

Comment: @JarrodHollingworth Thanks for the update, glad it worked out well!